# I want to initialize the auto number of the ACCESS table with relation setting

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access application, which is under development, some test data has already been created and should change to actual operation.
There are many tables which have a relationship, connecting each table by id number. I want to reset the ID number from 1 continuously.

I researched some method, all the methods are below,

Data deleting, initializing and adding.

Above method used, maybe all data was reset and I must input them again.

Is it possible to restructure data and relationship remains unchanged?

Comment: clear tables, compact database, done.

Comment: if access version is bigger than 97, you can insert by SQL command one row with id = 0 or any other initial value and next autonumber will be assigned with +1.

Comment: Maybe some of these [ADOX Programming Code Examples](http://allenbrowne.com/func-ADOX.html) will help.

Comment: @4dmonster I think that this was already possible back in the old days of Access 2.0. :-)

Comment: Since an ID number should not have any meaning... just overcome yourself and try to ignore the gaps (yeees, I know, that's not easy).

Comment: @WolfgangKais before 2000 you had to compact DB to reset autonumber. Since 2000 it applies immediatly. And 97 checked max ID in table.